# AWS SageMaker Studio Jupyter Notebook opening error

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm new on the AWS Environment; yesterday tried launching a Jupyter Notebook application on AWS SagegMaker Studio. I faced two issues - Max User Profiles per Account and Max Running Apps per Account - and was able to resolve the cases by contacting the support team. Then when I tried launching the app, the system reported this issue:

"Unable to create app [default] for user [(DOMAIN NAME)] in domain [(DOMAIN ADDRESS)]. Reason: The account-level service limit 'Jupyter Apps running on system instances' is 0 Apps, with current utilization of 0 Apps and a request delta of 1 Apps. Please contact AWS support to request an increase for this limit."

I contacted the support team for multiple times to solve this situation, but all of them weren't able to manage it. Any similar situations that previously happened, or any clues on how to manage this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Request an increase in studio jupyter apps running on system instances through aws support

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139890)